# Reshape data into long columns based on variable in R for IRR

Tags: r, dcast

There are thousands of answers describing how to reshape from wide to long and organize by certain variables. I do not know what I'm not wrapping my head around. 
I need to organize rows that originally begin as  rater, obs, val1, val2, etc. Into columns under rater for [IRR](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Inter-rater_reliability/).

Given a format similar to my data that can be created with:

```
r1 <- c('bob', 'sally', "george", "bob", "sally", "george")
r2 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
r3 <- c("bad", "good", "good", "good", "good", "bad")
r4 <- c("bad", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "bad")
df=data.frame(r1,r2,r3,r4)
df = setNames(df,  c('rater','obs', 'val1', 'val2'))
```

I need to organize the data into columns based on 'rater'. Anything that works would be great, especially if 'obs' (observation number) could be preserved, e.g., obs1_val1, obs1_val2, etc.

For something along the lines of:

```
dcast(df, obs ~ rater)
```

Which creates:

```
   obs   bob   george sally
1   1    bad   good   bad
2   2    good  bad    good
```

However, this aggregates and removes the values for val2.

Rather, I need something along the lines of:

```
              bob   sally   george
  obs1_val1   bad   good    good
  obs1_val2   bad   bad     good
  obs2_val1   good  good   bad
  obs2_val2   good  good   bad
```

Looking at similar [responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143428/why-cant-one-have-several-value-var-in-dcast), I see the recommendation to `melt` and then `dcast` [I don't actually want to aggregate - but rather just stack in columns].

As the strings for val1 and val2 should be considered factors I've tried:

```
df$"val1" <- factor(df$val1, levels=c("bad","good"))
df$"val2" <- factor(df$val2, levels=c("bad","good"))
```

without any effect. Getting:

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

    obs bob  george sally
1   1   2      2     2
2   2   2      2     2
```

which is not helpful.

?

Comment: `dcast(melt(df, 1:2), variable + obs ~ rater)` or `dcast(melt(df, 1:2), obs + variable ~ rater)` if you want it to be sorted by `obs`

Comment: Looking at the output I'm not sure what 1:2 selects. ?

Comment: The first two columns

Comment: As the id.vars.  That was my guess. Just making sure because I'm having some trouble transitioning to the actual data. Namely the factors are being displayed as numerics.

Comment: Related: [*dcast error: ‘Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length’*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33051386/2204410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider rbinding `dcast()` calls for both *val1* and *val2* columns. Additionally, add a column to capture the corresponding *val* value (since it is dropped during `dcast`). Hence, the use of `data.frame()`:

```
rdf <- rbind(data.frame(val=c("va1"), dcast(df, obs ~ rater, value.var="val1")),
             data.frame(val=c("va2"), dcast(df, obs ~ rater, value.var="val2")))

#   val obs  bob george sally
# 1 va1   1  bad   good  good
# 2 va1   2 good    bad  good
# 3 va2   1  bad   good   bad
# 4 va2   2 good    bad  good
```

Should there be many *val* columns, iterate with `lapply()` and then `do.call(rbind, ...)` on list:

```
valcols <- names(df)[grep("val", names(df))] 

dfList <- lapply(valcols, function(v) {
  data.frame(val=c(v), dcast(df, obs ~ rater, value.var=v))
})    
rdf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Finally to render the character variables to factors call `as.factor()` in an `sapply()`:

```
rdf <- data.frame(sapply(rdf, as.factor))
str(rdf)

# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ val   : Factor w/ 2 levels "val1","val2": 1 1 2 2
# $ obs   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1 2
# $ bob   : Factor w/ 2 levels "bad","good": 1 2 1 2
# $ george: Factor w/ 2 levels "bad","good": 2 1 2 1
# $ sally : Factor w/ 2 levels "bad","good": 2 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The tidyverse option.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   gather(val1, val2, key = "eval", value = "value") %>% 
   spread(key = rater, value = value)
```

You can then choose to either drop the 'obs' column completely or merge 'obs' and 'eval' into one using `unite()`.

Comment: This is still in the 'wide' rather than long format. Not listing under 'rater'.

Comment: @Donnied: I agree but it's what the OP showed as a successful example in his/her post.

Comment: Who was the OP?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, that was you. Apologies. Can you then please modify the 'Rather, I need something along the lines of:' to reflect what exactly it is you are looking for.

Comment: That was what I was looking for - all values listed under the individual raters. And as described in the second sentnce: " I need to organize rows that originally begin as rater, obs, val1, val2, etc. *Into columns under rater for IRR*. "

Comment: Just reorganise the rows using `select()` and if you need to rename them you can use either `rename()` or `mutate()`.