# Factors being converted / displayed as integers in R after dcast

Tags: r, dcast

In the question presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196676/reshape-data-into-long-columns-based-on-variable-in-r-for-irr), sample data was converted from wide to long format using `dcast`. However, when attempting to apply the same approach to the actual data set (or an abbreviated form thereof):

```
dcast(melt(smallz, 1:2), behavior_num + variable ~ rater)
```

The factors for the variable (i.e., the original column 3), are displayed as integers.

(Why) are the factors being displayed as integers? 
How might they still be displayed as characters?

The smaller data subset is here:

```
structure(list(rater = structure(c(2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Al", 
"Dan", "Gabi", "john", "bill", "rebecca", 
"ted"), class = "factor"), behavior_num = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 
58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 
66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 
73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 73L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
112L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 122L, 
127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 
132L, 132L, 132L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 133L, 135L, 
135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 142L, 142L, 142L, 142L, 142L, 
142L, 142L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 147L, 147L, 
147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 
155L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 162L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 
173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 
179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 182L, 182L, 182L, 182L, 
182L, 182L, 182L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 186L, 
186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 186L, 193L, 193L, 193L, 193L, 193L, 
193L, 193L, 196L, 196L, 196L, 196L, 196L, 196L, 196L, 204L, 204L, 
204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 
206L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 211L, 211L, 211L, 
211L, 211L, 211L, 211L, 211L, 231L, 231L, 231L, 231L, 231L, 231L
), self.and.tech = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("more commonly reinforced", 
"neither a history of reinforcement or punishment are discernible from the behaviors evidenced", 
"more commonly punished"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("rater", 
"behavior_num", "self.and.tech"), row.names = c(NA, -294L), class = "data.frame"
```

Comment: Is your data correct?  It looks like "Dan" has duplicate behavior for number 211

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Could that have been the problem? I did three things - I fixed the duplicate entry, I imported as csv (rather than xls), and simplified the variable values. It works now.

Comment: What may have happened was the dcast function caught the duplicate value and aggregated to count instead of copying the values over.